# Java.util.Calendar - milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970

Tags: java, calendar

Program followed by output.  Someone please explain to me why 10,000,000 milliseconds from Jan 1, 1970 is November 31, 1969.  Well, someone please explain what's wrong with my assumption that the first test should produce a time 10,000,000 milliseconds from Jan 1, 1970.  Numbers smaller than 10,000,000 produce the same result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String x = "10000000";
    long l = new Long(x).longValue();
    System.out.println("Long value: " + l);

    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    c.setTimeInMillis(l);
    System.out.println("Calendar time in Millis: " + c.getTimeInMillis());

    String origDate = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);  
    System.out.println("Date in YYYY-MM-DD format: " + origDate);

    x = "1000000000000";
    l = new Long(x).longValue();
    System.out.println("\nLong value: " + l);

    c.setTimeInMillis(l);
    System.out.println("Calendar time in Millis: " + c.getTimeInMillis());

    origDate = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);  
    System.out.println("Date in YYYY-MM-DD format: " + origDate);
}
```

> Long value: 10000000
>
> Calendar time in Millis: 10000000
>
> Date in YYYY-MM-DD format: 1969-11-31
>
> Long value: 1000000000000
>
> Calendar time in Millis: 1000000000000
>
> Date in YYYY-MM-DD format: 2001-8-8

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The dates you print from `Calendar` are local to your timezone, whereas the epoch is defined to be midnight of 1970-01-01 in UTC. So if you live in a timezone west of UTC, then your date will show up as 1969-12-31, even though (in UTC) it's still 1970-01-01.

Answer (score 6):

First, `c.get(Calendar.MONTH)` returns 0 for Jan, 1 for Feb, etc.

Second, use `DateFormat` to output dates.

Third, your problems are a great example of how awkward Java's Date API is. Use Joda Time API if you can. It will make your life somewhat easier.

Here's a better example of your code, which indicates the timezone:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final DateFormat dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.FULL);

    long l = 10000000L;
    System.out.println("Long value: " + l);
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    c.setTimeInMillis(l);
    System.out.println("Date: " + dateFormat.format(c.getTime()));

    l = 1000000000000L;
    System.out.println("\nLong value: " + l);
    c.setTimeInMillis(l);
    System.out.println("Date: " + dateFormat.format(c.getTime()));
}
```

Comment: Very helpful; you answered my question a bit indirectly.  The time zone thing was causing me the most confusion.  The improved code is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

[Calendar#setTimeInMillis()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeInMillis(long)) sets the calendar's time to the number of milliseconds after Jan 1, 1970 **GMT**.

[Calendar#get()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get(int)) returns the requested field adjusted for the calendar's timezone which, by default, is **your machine's local timezone**.

This should work as you expect if you specify "GMT" timezone when you construct the calendar:

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` were poorly designed leading to this sort of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your timezone is most likely lagging behind GMT (e.g., GMT-5), therefore 10,000,000ms from epoch is December 31 1969 in your timezone, but since months are zero-based in `java.util.Calendar` your `Calendar`-to-text conversion is flawed and you get 1969-11-31 instead of the expected 1969-12-31.

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out yourself if you change your first `c.setTimeInMillis(l);` in `c.clear();`