# Java time since the epoch

Tags: java, time, simpledateformat, epoch

In Java, how can I print out the time since the epoch given in seconds and nanoseconds in the following format :

```
java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

My input is:

```
long mnSeconds;
long mnNanoseconds;
```

Where the total of the two is the elapsed time since the epoch `1970-01-01 00:00:00.0`.

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263376/java-util-calendar-milliseconds-since-jan-1-1970), you should be able to modify it for your needs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this

```
public static String format(long mnSeconds, long mnNanoseconds) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.");
    return sdf.format(new Date(mnSeconds*1000))
           + String.format("%09d", mnNanoseconds);
}
```

e.g.

```
2012-08-08 19:52:21.123456789
```

---

if you don't really need any more than milliseconds you can do

```
public static String format(long mnSeconds, long mnNanoseconds) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    return sdf.format(new Date(mnSeconds*1000 + mnNanoseconds/1000000));
}
```

Comment: That's what I would do except that the format he wants it in doesn't output more than milliseconds (.SSS) so that last String.format() call is kind of unwanted.

Comment: Great answer - and FAST!  Thanks.  Fredrik, it does do ms - that is what the + String.format("%09d", mnNanoseconds); part does!

Comment: @user1585643 you missed my point. That part does milliseconds AND micros and nanos. The format string in the question only has milliseconds (three decimals) so I assumed that is what you wanted not nine decimals.

Comment: @user1585643 Its not clear in the question whether you wanted milli-seconds, micro-seconds or nano-seconds. These are not the same thing at all. BTW I tend to record and display micro-seconds in my systems as getting anything more accurate than this is very hard.

Answer (score 27):

Use this and divide by 1000

```
long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("Epoch : " + (epoch / 1000));
```

Comment: This displays **current** seconds since epoch. It's off topic.

Comment: Yep, I completely misread the question for some reason, thought he was asking for seconds.

Comment: Completely agree that is it off topic, but it is what I was searching for, and one of first results was here. My query was java epoch time and my goal was to get the current epoch time

Answer (score 11):

## tl;dr

```
    Instant                        // Represent a moment in UTC.
    .ofEpochSecond( mnSeconds )   // Determine a moment from a count of whole seconds since the Unix epoch of the first moment of 1970 in UTC (1970-01-01T00:00Z). 
    .plusNanos( mnNanoseconds )    // Add on a fractional second as a count of nanoseconds. Returns another `Instant` object, per Immutable Objects pattern.
    .toString()                    // Generate text representing this `Instant` object in standard ISO 8601 format.
    .replace( "T" , " " )          // Replace the `T` in the middle with a SPACE. 
    .replace "Z" , "" )            // Remove the `Z` on the end (indicating UTC).
```

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, `java.sql.Date`, and more. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) team also advises migration to java.time.

### `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution up to nanoseconds.

```
long mnSeconds = … ;
long mnNanoseconds = … ;

Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( mnSeconds ).plusNanos( mnNanoseconds );
```

Or pass both numbers to the `of`, as two arguments. Different syntax, same result.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( mnSeconds , mnNanoseconds );
```

To get a String representing this date-time value, call `Instant::toString`.

```
String output = instant.toString();
```

You will get a value such as `2011-12-03T10:15:30.987654321Z`, standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Replace the `T` with a SPACE if you wish. For other formats, search Stack Overflow to learn about [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.Date` class has a constructor which accepts the epoch milliSeconds.

Check the [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) and try to make use of it.

Comment: java.util.Date might be the better solution since java.sql.Date is meant for use with jdbc databases.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on the values of you mnSeconds and mnNanoseconds but all you need to do with a formatter like that one (which has millisecond precision) is to create a java.util.Date. If mnNanoseconds is the number of nanoseconds on top of your mnSeconds, I would assume it to be something like

`Date d = new Date(mnSeconds*1000+mnNanosecods/1000000)`

Then it is a matter of formatting it with your formatter before printing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
new java.util.Date(mnSeconds);
```

and then [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format your output.

Nanoseconds are not supported by Date. You have to manually add Nanoseconds or use some framework (is there one?).

Comment: The OP only requires milliseconds and [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) does support this. No need for extra frameworks.