# How to interpret data-time in Twitter DM

Tags: java, twitter, time

If I save the source html from a Direct Message page in Twitter, I find something like this, which seems to include a detailed timestamp:

<span class="_timestamp" data-aria-label-part="last" data-time="1469168058" data-long-form="true" data-include-sec="true">Jul 22</span>

If i read this data (in Java for example, including only java.io.*) is there a way that I can convert the number in `data-time="1469168058"` to date and time with hours and minutes, and maybe seconds?

Comment: And also a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8262333/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11871120/642706) and many more. Please search Stack Overflow before posting.

Comment: Please @Basil read my question more carefully.  I did not ask how to convert "seconds from epoch" in Java.  I began with Twitter and html scan.  If that is the same as seconds from Java epoch, fine.  Just tell me.  I did search and was not able to find references to "data-time".  Sorry.

Comment: As such this is not a duplicate question - for two reasons.  First, as I said above, this was a Twitter question.  Second, the "duplicate" answers are not exactly right - Twitter adjusts the seconds value for my local time.  The conversion is correct for local time *if* I do not set a time zone.

Comment: I do thank @Basil for pointing me in the direction of time display examples.  It saved me some "time" (pun) in coding my solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Unix/Posix time

A count around one and a half million usually means a count of whole seconds since the first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). This is commonly known as [Unix time or Posix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

## java.time

In Java a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) is represented by the [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class.

```
long input = 1_469_168_058L;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond ( input );
```

To see that same moment through the lens of a specific time zone, apply a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to produce a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Chicago" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone ( zoneId );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | instant: " + instant + " | zdt: " + zdt );
```

> input: 1469168058 | instant: 2016-07-22T06:14:18Z | zdt: 2016-07-22T01:14:18-05:00[America/Chicago]

This result matches the July 22 also included in your data block.