# Android inconsistency when dates are stored as longs and the time zone is changed

Tags: android, datetime

I have an Android app that is used by people in the UK and Ireland only, and there are no plans for this app to be used overseas.

In the app I store dates for various things, although I never need the full timestamp including the time of day, I only need the date.

So that I can compare dates easily, I've been creating calendar objects and clearing the values of the time, and using the milliseconds of that to store in the database.

```
public Calendar clearCalTime(long l) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(l);
    cal.clear(Calendar.HOUR);
    cal.clear(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
    cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
    cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
    return cal;
}
```

The issue has been that if users change the timezone, for some reason the dates start messing up, e.g by saving things to the wrong day. The timezones could be anything, I have no control over what the users set.

I've tried setting the timezone to UTC but this doesn't work either. Is there any way to just disregard the timezones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. You are going to have to set TimeZone going in and out of your storage.

You'll need to do this:

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

in your code to make it consistent.

See this SO: [Java.util.Calendar - milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263376/java-util-calendar-milliseconds-since-jan-1-1970)

Alternatively use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) when dealing with complicated Date/Time math.

Comment: Thanks - I'll keep messing around with the time zones, I have set them manually in some places.

Comment: The odd thing is that it seems to be correct for when the timezone is set to -x but when it is set to +x the dates are incorrect...